# Gradle/Maven configs for Artifactory Java Client

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

I am trying to use the [Artifactory Java Client](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-client-java) in my code and Gradle build but cannot discern a few details about the JAR itself:

- What *exact* `mavenRepo` should I use to locate the JAR inside my `build.gradle`?
- What is the latest stable **official** version I should be using? According to [Bintray](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-tools/artifactory-client-java/0.17/view), it's either 0.17, 0.7 or 0.10 depending on what link you go to. According to `mvnrepo.org`, it's 0.16.
- What are the Gradle coordinates for this latest/stable/official version (`group:artifact:version.jar`)? Again, because I can't tell what binary repo is hosting this JAR, nor what version is officially the latest/stable, determining the proper coordinates is almost impossible.

---

**Update:**

It looks like the answer to the first question (maven repo) is:

```
maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-tools" 
}
```

Looks like `0.17` is also the official stable/latest version.

**So still needing help with the Gradle/Maven coordinates.** Leaving these answers up here in case any future-comers wonder the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The Artifactory Java client is officially distributed from [Bintray](https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-tools/artifactory-client-java/view). You can use the Maven repo you mentioned or better use Bintray's [jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

0.17 is indeed the latest version. You can use this URL to get the latest version in Bintray - https://bintray.com/jfrog/artifactory-tools/artifactory-client-java/_latestVersion
The coordinates you need to use are:

```
compile(group: 'org.jfrog.artifactory.client', name: 'artifactory-java-client-services', version: '0.17', ext: 'jar')
```